If the sum of the modulus of the coefficients of a monic polynomial is lower than 1, then the roots are lower than 1
Say we have a monic polynomial
$$ x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \dots + a_0 \in \mathbb C[x]$$
such that $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} |a_k| < 1$.
Then is it the case that all roots are in $B(0,1)$?
This was mentioned in the context of an introductory class to algebraic topology, in particular next to a bunch of exercises that were applications of the Borsuk-Ulam theorem and Brower's fixed point theorem.
Any idea if it can be solved with these kinds of tools? (Not necessarily these two theorems.)
Thanks in advance!

I don't know if there is a way using these theorems, but here is my attempt. Assume $z$ is a root such that $|z|> 1$, then
$$
|z|^n = \left|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_k z^k \right| \leq \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} |a_k||z|^k
$$
dividing both sides by $|z|^n$ you have
$$
1 \leq \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} |a_k||z|^{k-n} < \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} |a_k|
$$
which is a contradiction.

Correct. Triangle inequality is all we need here.
